# Define column names of a table using pytables using a for loop inside the class definition

Tags: pytables

We know that if we need to define the column names of a table using pytables we can do it by the following way:

```
class Project(IsDescription):
    alpha = StringCol(20)
    beta  = StringCol(20) 
    gamma = StringCol(20)
```

where alpha, beta and gamma are the desired column names of the table. 
But suppose I would like to use a list "ColumnNames_list" which contains the column names as follows:
ColumnNames_list[0] = alpha, ColumnNames_list[1] = beta, ColumnNames_list[2] = gamma

Then how should I define the above class "Project"?

I tried with the following:

```
ColumnNames_list = []
ColumnNames_list[0] = alpha 
ColumnNames_list[1] = beta 
ColumnNames_list[2] = gamma

class Project(IsDescription):
    for i in range (0, 10):
        ColumnNames_list[i] = StringCol(20)
```

It's showing the error:

TypeError: Passing an incorrect value to a table column. Expected a Col (or subclass) instance and got: "2". Please make use of the Col(), or descendant, constructor to properly initialize columns.

Comment: You don't "declare" variables in python, so that's not your problem.  It would help to have more (any?) information on just how your "code is not working".

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable first outside the loop:

```
ColumnNames_list = []
for i in range (0, 10):
    ColumnNames_list.append(StringCol(20))
```

The reason I'm using `append()` rather than `ColumnNames_list[i] = StringCol(20)` is because you can't assign to an index that doesn't exist. Trying to assign ColumnNames_list[1] before it exists throws an `IndexError.`